# iReports 4.5.1 throwing error while using TABLE Report Element

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Hi I am getting the following error message while using the iReport designer Table Report Element:

```
Error filling print... java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.toPrintColumn(FillTable.java:116)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable$FillColumnEvaluator.visitColumn(FillTable.java:143)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable$FillColumnEvaluator.visitColumn(FillTable.java:130)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.StandardColumn.visitColumn(StandardColumn.java:73)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.evaluateColumns(FillTable.java:205)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.evaluate(FillTable.java:98)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.evaluate(JRFillComponentElement.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:473)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2021)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:616)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeaders(JRVerticalFiller.java:538)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:263)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:746)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:247)
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:879)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)   
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

I am using Stored Procedures that returns a cursor as output.

I have placed this Table Report element in one of my group header.

thanks in advance

Meeza

Comment: What version of iReport are you using?

Comment: iReport 4.5 to design the report.

Comment: Are you by chance using a where clause with dates in your procedure/SQL? If so, I know this isn't answering your question but if it is possible try installing iReport 3.7.6 and see if your problem still exists. I had the same boolean error occur with 4.5 and in 3.7.6 it no longer occurred.

Comment: Going back to an older version is not a viable solution I just have to come up with an alternate solution.

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PUBLISHER_AND_BOOKS (P_PUBLISHER_ID IN NUMBER,
PUBLISHER_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
BEGIN
OPEN PUBLISHER_CUR FOR
SELECT
BOOK_ID, BOOK_NAME,
AUTHOR_NAME, BOOK_ISBN,
PRICE,
PUBLISHER_NAME
FROM
BOOKS, PUBLISHER
WHERE
BOOKS.PUBLISHER_ID = PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_ID
AND PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_ID = P_PUBLISHER_ID;
END;

Answer (score 1):

Check in your style conditions if there's an evaluation with String. To ensure that everything works fine surround all the style conditions with `new Boolean( ... )`.